# ElasticSearch phrase search not working for wildcard search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a word index and I can't search phrases on elasticsearch. there is no result. I check tons of solutions but I can't implement them to my query.

My mapping looks like this;

```
PUT /words/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "text": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

(if the type is `text` everything worked as expected)

My elastic query looks like this;

```
GET /words/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "text",
                  "default_operator": "AND",
                  "query": "*foo bar baz*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 100,
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

But there is no data

| _id | _index | _score | _type | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |

I expect the record that has `foo bar baz` value,

| _id | _index | _score | _type | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| drDzzYQBu3ncIuw4vn10 | words | 0.0 | _doc | ***foo bar baz*** |

What is the problem? Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

"[Query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query)" is a full text query and will be optimized for text fields only , I suggest you to to use text type instead of keyword for this query.
As you are using AND operator , it will treat as phrase only.

Comment: I can't change the type because the code will ship to the prod server and I can't modify any prod elastic index. it works on only word searching.

Comment: You can create another index with modified mapping and use _reindex api to reindex data.